# Java RestCall ByPass UserCredentials By Default

Tags: spring-boot, httpclient, spring-resttemplate

I find a way to pass current user credentials by default to my rest call in java.I start application by a specific user and I dont want to enter password information in my rest call(spring resttemplate or something similar to call a rest service)

In c# UseDefaultCredentials =true gives this capability when LDAP authentication is active
I try to find similar way.

```
//c# code
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
```

Comment: Sorry, but still i look, what exactly you are asking for?

Comment: I dont want to enter username password information to my rest call.I want to send current credentials infos directly.

Comment: I have hands-on experience working in many authentication types. But i wonder here,  how to authenticate a user without username and password and also what does "current credentials infos directly " mean?

Comment: You say mean authentication using session tokens or JWT bearer tokens kind?

Comment: LDAP authentication I mean.I have two system both work on ldap authentication.I want to pass this ldap credentials by default.I make a rest call to call my other system so I try to find pass my current ldap info to another system.In .net code UseDefaultCredentials = true this work exactly as I want.